# Unsure about how to think about complex torus and related concepts. Please give constructive feedback.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, linear-transformations, transformation

Please give me constructive feedback and references.

Does there exist an isomorphic compactification from the $x,y$ plane to $[0,1]^2?$ And $x,y \ge 1.$ The reason I'm asking is because I want to map linear functions of the form $y=x+b$ to vertical lines of the form $x=1/2+\sigma$ compactified into $[0,1],^2$ study them in this space, and then be able to transform them back. Maybe "isomorphic compactification" is not the right term?

[image]

If I could rigorously define and understand such a map, then I could transport these linear functions to a compact space and this would allow me to study them as loops on a complex torus. I could parameterize the class of vertical lines in $[0,1]^2$ as $x=1/2 \pm \sigma$ where $\sigma=it;$ $t\in\Bbb R(0,1).$

I read this wikipedia page  and this question on mathoverflow and they were very helpful, but I still don't fully understand how to think about the complex torus, varieties, and algebraic torus.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20516/complex-torus-cn-%ce%9b-versus-cn

[Complex torus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus)

Comment: Your question is unclear, I think you need to learn the basic definition of $\Bbb{P}^n(k)$ and $\Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z})$, the former is the set of $k v$ for $v \in k^{n+1}-0$ (so $kv$ is a line in $k^{n+1}$ passing through the origin), the latter is the set of $a+\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z}$ for $a \in \Bbb{C}$ which is the additive group of $\Bbb{C}$ quotiented by the equivalence relation $a =b$ if $a-b\in\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: @reuns what exactly is unclear about it?

Comment: What is unclear to you ? Can you construct a bismooth function $\Bbb{C} \to (0,1)+i(0,1)$, do you see that it can't be biholomorphic (bounded entire functions are constant), where do you see a complex torus in there ?